# nginx config subdomain to subfolder reverse-proxy redirect

Tags: nginx, backend, nginx-reverse-proxy

we have a blog tat follows blog.website.com, and a website that is (www.)website.com.

They're separate WordPress installs (not that it matters, I think). Our idea is to do a redirect so the blog can be visited in website.com/blog/. So a single post would be website.com/blog/single-post, and a category website.com/blog/category-name.

A problem I can see happening is that the links in /blog/ wold still point to blog.website.com, so the redirect should take care of that too.

Currently we have this:

```
location ~ /blog(.*) {
      proxy_set_header        Host blog.website.com;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      proxy_pass              https://blog.website.com/$1;
}
```

It redirects the main blog page but nothing else. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep `blog.example.com` site working? If not, the most simple way is to change all the links via the WP database.

Comment: It needs to work as it's what we'll be using to go into the admin panel to add/edit/remove posts.